# How can I set a menu item click to respond to IBAction from another class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm pretty new to XCode/Objective-C/Cocoa. I want to implement a settings window for my app.

I have a `MainMenu.xib` which also holds my main Window. From the menu, I want to open a settings window. I created `Settings.xib` and appropriate `.h` and `.m` files to hold what that window would do.

Settings.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Settings : NSWindowController <NSApplicationDelegate>

-(IBAction)openSettings:(id)senderId;

@property (nonatomic, retain) Settings *thisWindow;

@end
```

Settings.m:

```
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation Settings

- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

// open preferences window
- (IBAction)openSettings:(id)senderId
{
    _thisWindow = [[Settings alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Settings"];
    [_thisWindow showWindow:self];
}

@end
```

I dragged my `Preferences` menu item to first responder, and selected `openSettings:` from there.
However, the item is still disabled and I'm pretty sure it's because I did nothing to link the `Settings` interface to my `MainMenu.xib`, which works with `AppDelegate.h/m`.

How do I make this work? All other solutions I found didn't quite work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my `AppDeleate.m` to open the dialog instead. I linked the menu button to the AppDelegate object in the interface builder, and used `openSettings:`. Here's how it looks:

```
// open preferences window
- (IBAction)openSettings:(id)senderId
{
    _settingsWindow = [[Settings alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Settings"];
    [_settingsWindow showWindow:self];
}
```

In `AppDelegate.m`, instead of `Settings.m`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you clear you want to store your MainMenu and MainWindowController in a two separate classes.

1. Open your main menu nib-file. Remove window from the object tree.
2. Check in Project Settings -> General -> Main interface is still your MainMenu (without .xib-extension).
3. Create (implement) your custom MainWindowController class (with a nib-file may be).
4. Open AppDelegate class. In `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method create an instance of main window controller class, show the window

Use this code below

```
MainWindowController *controller=[[MainWindowController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindowController"];
[controller showWindow:nil];
[controller.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Here it is.

Comment: Not exactly - I have a main window which is in MainMenu.xib, and I have a Settings.xib which has another window - which I want to load from the MainMenu. I want to be able to hit "Preferences" or `⌘+,` for that matter, and load that window. For now after linking them in the interface editor, the item is still grayed out

Comment: @ChenAsraf did you set `File's Owner` of MainMenu.xib? Manage some class for this purpose (e.g. AppDelegate), create actions for menu items. In MainMenu.xib open menu (in Interface Builder), select the item and set Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so in your mainwindowcontroller, declare a property of type NSWindowController *settingsWindow.  Init it with the corresponding xib.

Then create a method called `-(void)openSettings`, with one line `[self.settingsWindow showWindow:self];`

Then also in your mainWindowController initialization, init a NSMenuItem, and set it's action to openSettings.  Then add that NSMenuItem to the Mainmenu where you'd like programmatically, like this

```
//mainMenu is your application's menu-- if you switched index to 1 it would be the 'File' menu
NSMenu *mainMenu = [[[NSApp mainMenu] itemAtIndex:0] submenu];
[mainMenu insertItem:newItem atIndex:4];
```